# mysql client fails to start on command line

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have been using the mysql command line client a lot before but I suddenly start getting this error when I try to launch it.

```
mysql: relocation error: mysql: symbol strmov_overlapp, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
```

The only significant event that comes into my mind is updating from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.4.  I'm not sure if there's anything else that I did to mess it up.

I tried uninstalling both the mysql server and mysql client like so but to no avail.

> ```
> sudo aptitude purge mysql-server-5.1
> ```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: write the command you try

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a library problem to me.

Try running ldconfig.

If that does not help I'd try to identify what package the mysql client comes with, remove and re-install that package. I'm not familiar with debian packages to know, but in redhat world mysql client has it's own package, separate from mysql-server and mysql-common.

Also try and identify what package libmysqlclient.so.16 comes from and uninstall/then re-install that package.

Also you have not changed architectures have you, e.g. moved from 32 to 64 bit?
If so you might want to check which arch the mysql binary is (use the file command) and make sure that you have the right arch libraries installed.